# Easepick Datepicker - change mindays for specific dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using the [easepick datepicker](https://easepick.com/) for a project. Everything works fine except one thing: I have a minday setting of 4 days, but now I want to set it to 7 days if the start date is in a specific date range. Is that possible somehow? I've set a variable for minday but it doesn't change in the LockPlugin.

```js
const DateTime = easepick.DateTime;
     
    /* const bookedDates = [
         "02.05.2022",
          "03.05.2022",
         "18.05.2022",
      ]*/
       
       
       var mindays = 4;
       
       bookedDates.map(d => {
          if (d instanceof Array) {
            const start = new DateTime(d[0], 'DD.MM.YYYY');
            const end = new DateTime(d[1], 'DD.MM.YYYY');

            return [start, end];
          }

          return new DateTime(d, 'DD.MM.YYYY');
      });
       
         console.log(bookedDates);
      const picker = new easepick.create({
        element: document.getElementById('vondatum'),
        css: [
          'https://www.driveaway.at/css/index.css',
          'https://www.driveaway.at/css/demo_hotelcal.css',
        ],
        lang: "de-DE",
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
        autoApply: true,
        calendars: 1,
        zIndex: 10,
        setup(picker) {
            picker.on('select', (e) => {
              var startdate = e.detail.start;
              var enddate = e.detail.end;
                //console.log(picker.getDate());
              
                var chkdate = convertDate(startdate);
                var chkdate = new Date(chkdate);
                
                var seasonstart = new Date("2022-06-25");
                var seasonend = new Date("2022-09-09");
                
                if(chkdate > seasonstart && chkdate < seasonend){
                    mindays = 7;
                } else {mindays = 4;}
               picker.config
                
             calcDate(startdate, enddate);
            
            });
            
        },
        plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
        RangePlugin: {
          tooltipNumber(num) {
            return num;
          },
          locale: {
            one: 'Tag',
            other: 'Tage',
          },
        },
        LockPlugin: {
          minDate: new Date(),
          minDays: mindays,
          inseparable: true,
          filter(date, picked) {
            if (picked.length === 1) {
              const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
              return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
            }

            return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
          },
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preselect` event and change LockPlugin options.

```js
 const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    css: [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.0/dist/index.css',
  ],
  plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
  LockPlugin: {
    minDays: 2,
    selectForward: true,
  },
  setup(picker) {
    const DateTime = easepick.DateTime;
    const lockPlugin = picker.PluginManager.getInstance('LockPlugin');
    
    picker.on('preselect', (e) => {
        const { start, end } = e.detail;
      
      const a = new DateTime('2022-06-20'); 
      const b = new DateTime('2022-07-13');
      
      if (start && start.isBetween(a, b, '[]')) {
        lockPlugin.options.minDays = 7;
      } else {
        lockPlugin.options.minDays = 2;
      }
      
      // refresh layout
      picker.renderAll();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker"/>
```